# Deleting fields from structure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have structure Vinlu of 1X36 in size:

```
        Vinlu = 

        vessel: [1x36 struct]
```

And each has 5 fields:

> > Vinlu.vessel

```
        ans = 

        1x36 struct array with fields:
        pixels
        indexNOmask
        indexWHOLEvessel
        widths
        Meanwidth
```

There are some vessel fields where pixels field is empty for e.g.:

> > Vinlu.vessel(1,4)

```
   ans = 

              pixels: [0x2 double]
         indexNOmask: [0x1 double]
    indexWHOLEvessel: [0x1 double]
              widths: [1x0 single]
           Meanwidth: NaN
```

I want to delete all those vessel fields from the structure whose pixel field is empty (irrespective of other fields). It may be possible that one or more field in vessel is empty but I want to delete those which have empty pixel field  such that I will get structure Vinlu of size 1 X n , where n<36

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First find the indices of the `vessel` structs that have an empty `pixels` field:

```
idx = cellfun('isempty', {Vinlu.vessel.pixels});
```

Then keep only those elements in `vessel` that have a non-empty `pixels` field:

```
Vinlu.vessel = Vinlu.vessel(~idx);
```

In a one-liner that would look like so:

```
Vinlu.vessel = Vinlu.vessel(~cellfun('isempty', {Vinlu.vessel.pixels}))
```